# Pre-90s story about aliens like H.Beam Pipers 'little fuzzy' who immitated Earth Fiction thinking it was real

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I cannot find the author or title of a story/series of stories about cute little fuzzy aliens who believed earth fiction was real and attempted to recreate/live it by taking on the roles of various great characters and situations in literature. One in particular took on the role of Sherlock Holmes. 
They were on a dual species in-habited planet and had been in conflict with the other species who were reptilian and hostile- the reptilian species largely moved off the planet due to a human bribe IRC.

Comment: Something like [this](https://archive.org/stream/Universe_03_1953-12_cape1736#page/n51/mode/2up) perhaps?

Comment: I was just about to post an answer about the Hokas. ^_^
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Hoka The Sherlock Holmes story was "The Adventure of the Misplaced Hound"

Comment: You can also find mention on the TVTropes site of the Slissii and how they quickly disappear from the stories.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you're thinking of the [Hoka](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?1850) series by [Poul Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poul_Anderson) and [Gordon Dickson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_R._Dickson)? There is a Sherlock Holmes character in ["The Adventure of the Misplaced Hound"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63910), which first appeared in [*Universe Science Fiction*, December 1953](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?199625+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Universe_03_1953-12_cape1736#page/n49/mode/2up).

> Through the door of 221-B came a horrible wail. Jones froze, ice running along his spine, and Geoffrey cursed and pulled out his raythrower. The scream sawed up an incredible scale, swooped down again, and died in a choked quivering. Geoffrey burst into the room, halted, and glared around.
>
> The place was a mess. By the light of a fire burning in the hearth, Jones could see papers heaped to the ceiling, a dagger stuck in the mantel, a rack of test tubes and bottles, and a "V.R." punched in the wall with bullets. It was hard to say whether the chemical reek or the tobacco smoke was worse. A Hoka in dressing gown and slippers put down his violin and looked at them in surprise. They he beamed and came forward to extend his hand.
>
> "Mr. Jones!" he said. "This is a real pleasure. Do come in."
>
> "Uh—that noise—" Geoffrey looked nervously around the room.
>
> "Oh, that," said the Hoka modestly. "I was just trying out a little piece of my own. Concerto in Very Flat for violin and cymbals. Somewhat experimental, don't y'know."
>
> Jones studied the great detective. Holmes looked about like any other Hoka—perhaps he was a trifle leaner, though still portly by human standards. "Ah, Lestrade," he said."And Watson—do you mind if I call you Watson, Mr. Jones? It seems more natural."

Comment: That's the one! the hoka, eh. Excellent, I think my kid will love those stories as I did, and hopefully also ignite in him an interest in some of the source literature the hoka replicated.

Comment: @JJGrey Glad I could help. If you want to, you can [accept](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.